# Byte array to Date in Java

Tags: java, date, timestamp, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a byte array with 4 bytes taken from a header of a drv and these 4 bytes represent the timestamp of a videoframe. So I need to convert these 4 bytes in a Date or a TimeStamp. Here is the array and the values that I got for the first frame:
 `byte[] array= {192, 242, 217, 84};`
I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: So those are four bytes... how were they generated? What do they represent? Without knowing the format, we'd just be guessing. What is "drv" here?

Comment: Is it big endian or little endian? (What's a "drv"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody I already did it. Here you have the solution:

```
String binary=toBin(head[11])+toBin(head[10])+toBin(head[9])+toBin(head[8]);
long unixSeconds=stringToInt(binary);

Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); 

String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); 


public static String toBin(byte numDec){

        int num= UnsignedBytes.toInt(numDec);
        if(num==0)
                return "00000000";

        String result=Integer.toBinaryString(num);
        int cont= 8-result.length()%8;
        if(cont!=8){
            for(int i=0; i<cont;i++){
                result="0"+result;
            }
        }
            return result;  }

public static long stringToInt(String bin){

          long result=0;
          bin= bin.trim();
          for(int i=bin.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
              String aux= String.valueOf(bin.charAt(i));          
              result+= Integer.parseInt(aux)* Math.pow(2, (bin.length()-1-i));
          }
          return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] array= {192, 242, 217, 84};
int timestamp = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getInt();
```

Comment: getLong(), not getInt()